# Disable rotation in Document Provider iOS app extension

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiinterfaceorientation, document-provider

I am making an app extension and would like the orientation to be portrait only. Can I prevent rotation of the app I'm extending to landscape, once my app extension has been loaded?

I tried adding these methods in my extension's UIViewController but it didn't seem to change anything:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate;

- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations
```